# Trouble with $I(\alpha) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\alpha x)}{x^2 + 1} dx$

Tags: derivatives, leibniz-integral-rule

I'm ultimately trying to solve
$$I(\alpha) = \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos (\alpha x)}{x^2 + 1} dx$$

by using differentiation under the integral. I realize that this is most easily done using residues but I'm intending this problem to introduce my advanced calculus 2/differential equations students to some interesting techniques before they take real analysis.

Differentiating under the integral a first time leads to

$$I'(\alpha) = \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{-x \sin (\alpha x)}{x^2 + 1} dx = - \dfrac{\pi}{2} + \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin (\alpha x)}{x(x^2 + 1)}dx$$

by making use of the Dirichlet integral and again to

$$I''(\alpha) = \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos (\alpha x)}{x^2 + 1} = I(\alpha)$$

To solve this second-order ODE we'll need two initial conditions. The integral for $I'(\alpha)$ leads to the incorrect result $I'(0) = 0$ but the rewritten version leads to the correct result of $I'(0) = -\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. I'm having trouble justifying this.

Any help or guidance is appreciated. I'll also settle for simpler arguments as to why $I'(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: "uniformly convergent for $\alpha=0$" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Since $\int \frac{x}{x^2+1} = \log\sqrt{x^2+1}$ what you really have in the first integral is $0\cdot \infty $ as $\alpha\to 0$. You could use the substitution $t=\alpha x$ and get the right limit, however.

Comment: It's better to start from $J(\alpha):=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(\alpha x)dx}{x(x^2+1)}$.

Comment: In case it is interesting from somebody, you can find several other questions about the same integral using [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=$%7B%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Ccos%20(%5Calpha%20x)%7D%7Bx%5E2%20%2B%201%7D%20dx%7D$) and [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Ccos%20(%5Calpha%20x)%7D%7Bx%5E2%20%2B%201%7D%20dx%24&p=1). See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: Since this is about differentiation under integral sign, I'll mention examples which do not use complex analysis: 
[How do you Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+1}dx$ Without Using Residue Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2505047),
[Evaluate the integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+1}dx$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2372949) (Probably you can find also other posts about this.)

Comment: When you created this post, you tagged it "unif".  This created a new tag on Math SE---usually we ask that users discuss the introduction of new tags before creating them.  However, I presume that this was a typological error, and have removed the tag---I don't know which tag you *meant* to apply, so please add an appropriate tag if you deem it necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{x}dx= \frac{\pi}{2} 
$$
but if $\alpha=0$, then
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{x}dx=0
$$
So, the equality
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{−x\sin(αx)}{x^2+1}dx=-\frac{π}{2}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(αx)}{x(x^2+1)}dx
$$
is true iff $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Ahh, good point! Thanks!

Comment: In fact, iff $\alpha>0$, since if $\alpha<0$ then $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{x}dx=-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Oh, that's true. Thanks.