# Can we evaluate $\int_0^\pi i^{\tan x} d x$ without contour integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, contour-integration, trigonometric-integrals

When encountering the integral
$$\int_0^\pi i^{\tan x} d x,$$
I feel interesting and wonder of its value. Since it is improper at $x=\frac{\pi}{2},$ I start to split into two intervals and investigate each of them.
$$\int_0^\pi i^{\tan x} d x =  \underbrace{ \int_0^\frac\pi2 i^{\tan x} d x}_{J} +  \underbrace{\int_ \frac\pi2 ^\pi i^{\tan x} d x}_{K}  .$$
Using the period of $\tan x$, I change the the second integral $K$ by the substitution $x\mapsto \pi-x$.
$$
K =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} i^{\tan (\pi-x)} d x =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} i^{-\tan x} d x
$$
Combining them yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(e^{\frac{\pi}{2} i \tan x}+ e^{-\frac{\pi}{2} i \tan x}\right) d x\\ & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(e^{\frac{\pi}{2} i \tan x}+ \overline{ e^{\frac{\pi}{2} i \tan x}}\right) d x\\
& =2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \tan x\right) d x
\end{aligned}
$$
which is surprisingly real.

Naturally, putting $t=\tan x$ transforms the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} t\right)}{1+t^2} d t \\
& =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} t\right)}{1+t^2} d t\\&=\Re \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{2} t i}}{1+t^2}dt \\
& =\Re \oint_\gamma \frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{2} z i}}{1+z^2} d z
\end{aligned}
$$
using contour integration along anti-clockwise direction of the path $$\gamma=\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2} \textrm{ where }  \gamma_{1}(t)=t+i 0(-R \leq t \leq R)  \textrm{ and } \gamma_{2}(t)=R e^{i t}  (0<t<\pi) \textrm{ as } R \rightarrow \infty.
 $$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\Re\left[2 \pi i \lim _{z \rightarrow i}(z-i) \frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{2} z i}}{z^2+1}\right] \\
& =\Re\left[2 \pi i \frac{e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}}{2 i}\right] \\
& =\pi e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}
\end{aligned}
**My Question**

Is there any **real** method to deal with integral?

Your comments and alternative methods are highly appreciated.

Comment: At what point do you want to have a real method? I'm asking because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{2} t i}}{1+t^2}dt$ is a known Fourier transform.

Comment: As @StefanLafon mentioned this is a known Fourier transform evaluated at $s=1$.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(a t\right)}{1+t^2} d t$ is very famous and has been posted a lot

Comment: One method would be Feynman's trick, in the vein of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2505047/how-do-you-evaluate-int-infty-infty-frac-cosxx21dx-without-usin?noredirect=1)

Comment: More details re: Fourier transform -- recognize that 
$$
I = \mathfrak{Re} \left( \mathcal{F} \left[ \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right] \bigg|_{\xi=-\pi/2} \right)
$$
where $\mathcal{F}[f](\xi)$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$, given by
$$
\mathcal{F}[f](\xi) := \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) e^{-  i \xi x} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
(or whatever convention you please). Luckily we know that
$$
\mathcal{F} \left[ \frac{1}{\alpha^2+x^2} \right] \bigg|_{\xi}
= \frac\pi {\alpha   e^{\alpha |\xi|}}
$$

Comment: In going from $i^{\tan x}$ to $e^{\frac{\pi}{2} i \tan x}$, you have chosen a particular branch of the (multi-valued) $i^{\tan x}$.  Explain that.  Also, explain why this wildly oscillatory integral converges.

Comment: Thank you all for your wonderful alternative methods and comments.  I had learnt much from you all.

Answer (score 3):

$$I =2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} t\right)}{1+t^2} \,dt=i\left(\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} t\right)}{t+i} \,dt -\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} t\right)}{t-i} \,dt\right)$$ Use the obvious changes of variable $u=t\pm i$ and expand the cosine
$$\int \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} t\right)}{t+i} \,dt=\cosh \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\int\frac{ \cos \left(\frac{\pi 
   u}{2}\right)}{u}\,du+i \sinh \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\int\frac{ \sin \left(\frac{\pi 
   u}{2}\right)}{u}\,du$$ Now $v=\frac{\pi u}{2}$ to face the usual sine and cosine integrals.

Back to $t$ and using the bounds
$$I=\pi\,e^{-\pi /2}$$